# Variable scope in Python nested function

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, scope, global-variables

**The first code snippet prints `[0, 3]` out.**

```
def func():
    a = [0]

    def swim():
        a.append(3)
        # a = [1]+a
        return a
    return swim()

print(func())
```

**The second code snippet raises error** "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment"

```
def func():
    a = [0]

    def swim():
        # a.append(3)
        a = [1]+a
        return a
    return swim()

print(func())
```

**Is `a` visible/accessible to function `swim` after all?**

Comment: @Pythonista Thanks! It seems 'a' becomes a local variable as soon as there is an assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems this is a commonly asked question as stated in [this link](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python). The reason is that variable `a` inside `swim` becomes a local variable as soon as there is an assignment to `a`. It shadows the external `a`, and local `a` is not defined before assignment in function `swim`, so the error rises.

Thanks for all your guys' answers!

Answer (score -1):

You are appending an element in the first code. The `id` of `a` is still same.

But at second code, you are re-defining variable `a`, which is changing the `id` of that variable. So that you get `UnboundLocalError`.

Answer (score -1):

When you do such assignment such as `a = [1] + a` or `a += [1]` in a scope, the variable would become local to that scope. In your case, that is function `swim()`.