# Understanding variable scope in nested functions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, nested, global-variables

I have the following functions in Python3.7

```
def output_report():
    sheet_dict = {1: 'All', 2: 'Wind', 3: 'Soalr'} 
    sheet_name = sheet_dict[sheet_num]
    file_name = f'{file_name}_{sheet_name}_row_{row_num}.csv' if row_num else 
    f'{file_name}_{sheet_name}.csv'
    return file_name

def test_file(x):
    file_name = output_report(sheet_num)
    return f'{x}_{file_name}'

def good_func():
    sheet_num = 2
    row_num = 2
    a = test_file('new file')
    return a
```

when I call:  `good_func()`

It raises an error that:

> NameError: name 'sheet_num' is not defined

But if I define sheet_name and row_num in the global scope like,

```
sheet_num = 2
row_num = 2
def good_func():
    a = test_file('new file')
    return a
```

the code works.

**My question:** My understanding was that in nested functions, the inner functions starts looking for the variables from itself and then goes to outer functions and finally to the global scope. Then, I expected the first function also runs, but that's not the case. What is that?
I read other [scope related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37473666/variable-scope-in-python-nested-function) but didn't find my answer.

Comment: I don't want to use global variables, as I only read the variable and don't change it. Maybe nanlocal would be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first case

```
def good_func():
    sheet_num = 2
    row_num = 2
    a = test_file('new file')
    return a
```

`sheet_num` and `row_num` are local to the function `good_func` and hence cannot be accessed in another function `output_report`

But when you do

```
sheet_num = 2
row_num = 2
def good_func():
    a = test_file('new file')
    return a
```

`sheet_num` and `row_num` become global variables accessible to all other functions, hence they are accessible in `output_report` as well

Also nested function are functions whose definition lies within another function like so, where `a` is accessible in `inner`

```
def outer():
    a = 1
    def inner():
        print(a)
    inner()

outer()
```

Calling another function inside a function like you do in `good_func` doesn't make them `output_function` nested.