# Difference in transmitting variables in an inner function in Python

Tags: python, function, variables

In Python, is there a difference between the following two codes both of which gives the same result c = [0,-10]?

```
def foo1():
    a = [0,1]

    def foo2():
        a[1] = -10

    foo2()
    return a


c = foo1()
```

and

```
def foo1():
    a = [0,1]

    def foo2(b):
        b[1] = -10

    foo2(a)
    return a


c = foo1()
```

Some commentator suggests this is answered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56303426/understanding-variable-scope-in-nested-functions-in-python). But it does not since my question asks about the passing of variables through an inner function whilst the linked question does not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding variable scope in nested functions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56303426/understanding-variable-scope-in-nested-functions-in-python)

Comment: Well, it's doing the same thing in two different ways.

Comment: @Jab: It does not answer my question. It shows the difference in the scope of the variables but says nothing about transmitting variables.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: You are saying option 1 is better because it is more succinct, right?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "transmitting" You're not "transmitting" anything here. You're essentially asking if there's a difference between passing a variable to a function vs using the local variable you would have passed anyway which both examples have access to already. This is not a very good example as there's no need to use the nested function here at all.

Comment: Yes, there is a difference between the two codes (as previous answers mentioned). Please clarify more your question (what is the measure and importance of difference and sameness).. E.g. I guess there is reference counts increase in the second code

Comment: @jab: Yes, I meant "passing" variables --- I did not use the conventional word. Yes, your rephrasing of my question is correct. But that link you provided does not answer this question.

Comment: @Hans no, that's not what I'm saying at all. I'm saying, those are two different ways of doing the same thing. This is a toy example, so it's hard to say which is a *better* approach. I mean, the better approach would be to remove the unnecessary inner function altogether! There would need to be a more realistic context for me to have a strong opinion, but generally I would favor passing arguments explicitly.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Understood and agree.

Comment: The difference is that in the second version, you can call `foo2()` with different variables as the argument, so it's more general. The first version is hard-coded to only work with the `a` variable.

Comment: It's the same reason that parameters are generally preferred over global variables, it's more flexible.

Comment: @Barmar: I am not sure it the second version is more general, because both 'b' and 'a' in 'foo2()' point to and are but two names of the same variable and changing one changes the other.

Comment: `b` only refers to the outer `a` if you pass `a` as the argument to `foo2`. Just because you aren't calling `foo2` on a different object in this example doesn't mean you *couldn't*.

Comment: @Hans But it doesn't have to be, the second version can be called with different variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first, `a` is a free variable whose value is taken from the nearest enclosing scope (in this case, the scope of `foo1`) that defines `a`.

In the second, `b` is a local variable initialized using the argument passed to `foo2` when it is called, which is the variable `a` defined in `foo1`.

In each case, you assign `-10` to the second "slot" of the same list.

Comment: But both 'a' and 'b' in 'foo2' point to and are merely two names of the same variable, right?

Comment: Right, though the second `foo2` has the *flexibility* to be called with a different argument. Your first `foo2` is hard-coded to refer to `a` from the enclosing scope. Put another way, the *object* that `foo2`'s free `a` refers to is fixed at the time `foo2` is defined. The object that `foo2`'s local variable `b` refers to is determined when `foo2` is *called*.